# Matplotlib x-axis ticks, fixed location for dates

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the timeline plot I’m making, I want date tickers to show only specified dates. (In my example I show tickers for events ‘A’, but it can be any list on tickers). I found how to do it when x-axis data is numeric (upper subplot in my example), but this won’t work with timestamp date type (bottom plot).

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

    myData = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-01-15','2019-02-10','2019-03-20','2019-04-17','2019-05-23','2019-06-11'],'cnt':range(6),'event':['a','b','a','b','a','b']})
    myData['date'] = [pd.Timestamp(j) for j in myData['date']]

start = pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')
stop = pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01')
inxa = myData.loc[myData['event'] == 'a'].index
inxb = myData.loc[myData['event'] == 'b'].index
# create two plots, one with 'cnt' as x-axis, the other 'dates' on x-axis.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(16,9))
ax[0].plot((0,6),(0,0), 'k')
ax[1].plot((start, stop),(0,0))


for g in inxa:
    ax[0].plot((myData.loc[g,'cnt'],myData.loc[g,'cnt']),(0,1),c='r')
    ax[1].plot((myData.loc[g,'date'],myData.loc[g,'date']),(0,1),c='r')
for g in inxb:
    ax[0].plot((myData.loc[g,'cnt'],myData.loc[g,'cnt']),(0,2),c='b')
    ax[1].plot((myData.loc[g,'date'],myData.loc[g,'date']),(0,2),c='b')
xlist0 = myData.loc[myData['event']=='a','cnt']
xlist1 = myData.loc[myData['event']=='a','date']

ax[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(xlist0))
# ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(**???**)
```

[image]

Comment: For `ax[1]` How many or Where do you want tick labels? I imagine there is a duplicate Q&A here on SO, just need to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a sufficient duplicate, maybe I didn't look hard enough.  There are a number of ways to do this:

Converting to *numbers* first or using the *underlying* values of a Pandas DateTime Series

```
xticks = [mdates.date2num(z) for z in xlist1]
# or
xticks = xlist1.values
```

and at least a couple ways to use it/them

```
ax[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(xticks))
ax[1].xaxis.set_ticks(xticks)
```

---

[Date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)
[How to set the xticklabels for date in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385184/how-to-set-the-xticklabels-for-date-in-matplotlib)
[how to get ticks every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790378/how-to-get-ticks-every-hour)
...

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate ether. Both ways work fine and do what I need. Thank you.